# How can I return two types of variables with is condition?

Tags: solidity, remix

```
contract Storage {  
    
    bytes32 a;
    bytes32 b;
    
    string er = "Denied";
    
    function checkOffers(bytes32 value) public view returns(uint256 , string memory){
    
          if(a == b){
              value = a;
              return block.number;
          } else {
              return er;
          }
    }
}
```

I need to return the block number when the two values are equal and write a value to blockchain and return the error message when values not equal.

Answer (score 1):

In Solidity when you wrote this statement in signature function:

```
... returns(uint256 , string memory)
```

you said it that this function must to return necessarily a uint and a string.

In your code, you return sometimes a uint and at times string. To solve this problem, you can set default value when you return a string and not uint and viceversa. For example:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Storage {
    bytes32 a;
    bytes32 b;

    string er = "Denied";

    function checkOffers(bytes32 value) public view returns(uint256, string memory){
        if(a == b){
            value = a;
            return (block.number, "");
        }else{
            return (0, er);
        }
    }
}
```